# Exclude a file based on keys from another

Tags: bash

I've got file1.txt formatted like

```
key100 3 5 7
key101 2 5 6
key103 1 0 0
key202 3 2 1
key204 0 0 0
```

where keyXXX is unique (and it's sorted by keyXXX).

Then I've got a list of unique keys (also sorted) in file2.txt to exclude like

```
key100
key200
key202
```

Is there a bash command I can run that will return file1.txt with all keys excluded that were in file2.txt?

The output from this example would look like:

```
key101 2 5 6
key103 1 0 0
key204 0 0 0
```

file1.txt is very large, so looping through each file2.txt key and using grep -v seems slow. comm seems like what I'm going for, but needs the whole line to match. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fgrep -v -f FILE2 FILE1 > RETURN.txt
```

is a bit faster than running several grep processes (as `fgrep` searches for fixed strings not regexps and it won't open the file for every single pattern line, like looping through FILE2 would do).

Answer (score 1):

If `file2.txt` is not prohibitively large then `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next} !($1 in a)' file2.txt file1.txt` should work for you.

If it is then, assuming both files are sorted on the key, it should be possible to read the next key from `file2.txt` on demand while processing lines in `file1.txt` and so only keep a single key and line in memory at once.